# Answer "Justification for travel support" in conference registration form

Tags: conference, application

In a conference registration form I found a slot to be filled having the header "Justification for travel support". I don't quite understand what they are asking precisely. What is the appropriate way to fill this in?

I remark that they ask for resume and research statement in different sections of the registration form for the purpose of attributing funding.

Comment: what is the conference? can you link their website please

Comment: "I don't quite understand what they are asking precisely." Are you able to ask *them* what they're asking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With some conferences/courses, free or subsidised travel (and even lodging) is provided by the conference organisers and/or sponsors for a certain subset of participants. The eligibility criteria varies - and may include students (undergraduate or postgraduate) or participants from listed developing countries. What I quoted are just examples. For specifics, you should refer to the details stated on the conference website or printed brochure and see if you qualify for such assistance/subsidy (and then decide if you wish to avail yourself of it). If they didn't give these details on the website or publicity materials, it is appropriate to write to them for clarification.

Comment: If the form has only space for a one-liner, I think one of "student", "early career researcher", "unemployed", "developing country", or even "minority group", would do. If the free space is one page or so, probably they want a more detailed statement in which you detail how well the conference fits with your research themes and how important it would be for your professional development.

Comment: @Federico I'm in full agreement. Good advice.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, it is one line (but you can type in it without space constraint). Since they ask for a resume and a research statement in other sections, I take it that your advice applies to this situation. Thank you. And thank you Deepak.

Answer (score 15):

Do you need assistance from the conference organizers to pay for your travel to the conference and/or accommodation? If so, give your reasons here. If not, ignore the box.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

- Presenting a paper at the conference.
- No institutional/employer travel funding.
- No third-party travel funding.
- No (significant) personal wealth.