# Where does one get the funding to participate in a conference as a student?

Tags: conference, fees

I received a few invitations to conferences on physics. In Australia, in Japan, in France, and others. I am finishing graduate school. But how can I take part in these conferences, if I need 1,000 Euros for participation in Sweden and I also need to get there? Are there are funds to promote?

Comment: Please fix your caps key and title.

Comment: I would discuss with your advisor -- some conferences are well worth attending and your advisor may be able to help you find funds. Others are predatory. But we don't match people to funding sources here.

Comment: What facilities are you considering taking?

Answer (score 1):

Ask your advisor, who's likely to know more than anyone here. It's possible that the university/department allocates some funding for graduate students to attend conferences, in which case you would qualify. It's possible that the professor has a grant that provides such a component, and he's willing to fund you. Finally, it's possible that the conference itself provides [some funds for people who need travel support](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/129939/answer-justification-for-travel-support-in-conference-registration-form).

You will need to look to know the answer.